# Error trying get capture stream id with specific tab id

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to get stream id of provided tab in popup window, but always get error:

```
popup.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.
```

How I do it:

1. Open popup html page

   `chrome-extension://{ext_id}/dist/popup/popup.html?configure=true`
2. By code of popup, create new tab and store its id/tab_model
3. Load content scipt by `chrome.scripting.executeScript` and listen some events
4. By events I want to init `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`, therefore I call:

```
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent((tab: chrome.tabs.Tab) => {
            targetTabId: this.tab.id,
                consumerTabId: tab.id,
        })
        chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId(
            {
                targetTabId: this.tab.id,
                consumerTabId: tab.id,
            },
            this.init.bind(this)
        );
    });
```

As a consumer tab I set current tab, as a target tab which I want to record.

5. In init method I have something like:

```
 async init(streamId: string): Promise<void> {
        const streamConstraints = {...this.defaultStreamConstraints};
        streamConstraints.audio.mandatory.chromeMediaSourceId = streamId;
        streamConstraints.video.mandatory.chromeMediaSourceId = streamId;

        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints);
```

Argument streamId is always undefined, cause I'm getting error.

What I'm missing?

My manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Chrome Tab Recorder",
  "version": "2.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "video Records Tool",
  "permissions": [
    "tabCapture",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "downloads",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "storage",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "dist/popup/popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "worker.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message means there was no physical user interaction in this tab. You can only use this API in the context where such interaction just occurred e.g. inside a click handler, see also the list of actions at the end of [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).

Comment: Are there any ways to avoid clicking on extension? I'm writting bot that open target tab and record it. Maybe some special permission or else?

Comment: There's nothing an extension can do, but you can probably restart Chrome with `--allowlisted-extension-id=ID` command line where ID is the id of your extension.

Comment: That's exactly what i need, thank you! I'm not sure how to mark you comment as answer, maybe if you write it as aswer I'll can.